# How do I open the Arabic keyboard by default within my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I set my keyboard default to be the Arabic keyboard programmatically?
I don't want a user of my application to have to manually go to Settings > Keyboard > Arabic.

I want to have the Arabic keyboard as the default within my iPhone application, is this doable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's documentation on [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) states:

> **Keyboards and Input Methods**
>
> Whenever the user taps in an object capable of accepting text input,
>   the object asks the system to display an appropriate keyboard.
>   Depending on the needs of your program and the user’s preferred
>   language, the system might display one of several different keyboards.
>   Although your application cannot control the user’s preferred language
>   (and thus the keyboard’s input method), it can control attributes of
>   the keyboard that indicate its intended use, such as the configuration
>   of any special keys and its behaviors.

...

> To facilitate the language preferences of different users, iOS also
>   supports different input methods and keyboard layouts for different
>   languages, some of which are shown in Figure 4-2. The input method and
>   layout for the keyboard is determined by the user’s language
>   preferences. Input for some of these keyboards takes place in multiple
>   stages.

So the short answer is No, you cannot bring up a specific language in the keyboard programmatically.

Comment: One could make the keyboard oneself, but that's a slow and difficult process. See the app WolframAlpha for reference.

Comment: @Emil Yes, but there is the added difficulty that Arabic reads right to left, so implementing that with the correct cursor position is a real pain. Good point, though.