# How to get the Arabic keyboard in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using to language one is English and is Arabic Language. So I want to know how to get Arabic language keyboard in iPhone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [open arabic keyboard by default,iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762121/open-arabic-keyboard-by-default-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With its global nature iPhone does support multiple languages and so does its keyboard. It has support for 42 languages. By default it uses English for its keyboard layout. But you can change or add more languages to its keyboard.

Go to **Settings->General->KeyBoard->International Keyboards**. Here you can set your keyBoard language type according to your requirement and if you want to achieve this thing through your code it's not possible.

Comment: Just to clarify: it is your users' choice to select which keyboards to show, not yours.

Comment: @Costique: yes you are right,I have already mentioned that you can't achieve it through your code.it's totally depend on user's.

Answer (score 7):

You change Setting in simulator/Device

Go to **Settins->General->keyboard->international keyboards->add New Keyboard->select Arabic**

After setting change When You open the Keyboard and press the language change button and select choice language ....

If you do not know "language change button" in keyboard the see this [url](http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/)

Comment: yeah thanks for the advice but i am making project that when i click on the arabic button(some button) then the view will appear and there is text field when i click on that textfield then automatically arabic keyboard will appear..thanks